# Changing a 240v plug with 4 wires to 240v plug 3 wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, 240v

I have a outlet that is 240V with 4 wires.  I want to change it to 3 wires, I am assuming the black is also a hot wire. With the volt meter I get 220V touching the two red wires and 110V when i touch the black to ground.

I want to change the plug to a 3 wire and I am not sure what to do with the black wire, can i just put a wire nut on it and push in the box?? Any help would greatly be appreciated. I don't need another shocking experience

[image][image]

Comment: That is very strange that you're getting 110 volts from black to ground. What are you getting from black to each red? What type is your current outlet? How about a photo of the front of your current outlet?

Comment: Can you get us a photo looking into the back of the current box?  Also, what type *is* that outlet? It looks like it *can't* be a NEMA 10 or a NEMA 14 from the back housing shown...

Comment: What kind of device is that?  If it is a range or electric clothes dryer, I though a 4 to 3 wire conversion is not in the spirit of electrical code.

Comment: What appliance do you want to power through this receptacle?

Comment: it says on the outlet, 125v / 220v, it was used to power a paper cutter in my shop, but then used for another device that was 110 v. I am thinking the way the plug was wired you could run either 220 or 110 as long as the plug you plug into it was set up right, it has four prongs, not twist lock. similar to the picture in this link except 20A     http://www.ebay.com/itm/30-Amp-125-250-Volt-Male-Female-Twist-Lock-Set-4-Prong-Plug-Nema-L14-30P-L14-30R-/121899201031

Comment: @RonGinn -- can you *please* get us a photo of the *front* of the current receptacle?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your wires are in conduit.  You need to follow the wires a bit more and figure out what they're being used for.  They should go back to a circuit breaker, and it should be a 2-pole (240V) breaker.  Turning off that breaker should turn off two of the wires.  I have no idea what's going on with the third (black) wire.

Those are the two wires to put on L1 and L2 on your NEMA 6-20 receptacle.  The ground goes to ground obviously.  NEMA 6 does not use neutral.

Comment: That is what I thought, I did not think there was a neutral in 220 v.

Comment: and yes they are in conduit, and they do go to the 240v breaker, the black wire I am not sure but there is voltage there to ground 110v.

Comment: 110V to ground will be true for any "hot" in a 110/220 (aka 120/240) split-phase system.  Ground is center-tap on the transformer (same as neutral by the way). The black wire is a real wildcard.  What exactly was the old connector?  I'm unclear why it has 3 hots and a ground going to 4 different terminals.

Comment: Looking at the terminal connector on the ground are you in a country that has 3 phase power? If black to ground is 120 what is black to red 1 and black to red 2? On a 4 wire usually 1 is neutral, 1 ground and the 2 hotts. If it were 3 phase you would see similar voltages red 1 to black as red  to black and red to red.